# How to run webpack in production in a package.json script in windows with other commands?

Tags: json, node.js, windows, webpack, gulp

I am using MERN stack and running windows 10. I am trying to run this `npm run` command from the `package.json` file.

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "set NODE_ENV=production webpack && gulp",
    "postinstall": "npm run build",
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
```

When I run `npm run build` I get the following results:
[terminal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpcl2.png)

What happens is it looks like gulp runs and that is it. My bundle is not optimized for production at all. I will include the webpack file incase it is needed.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/app.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'public/build/bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'public/build/bundle.map'
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? [
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
              NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
            }
          }),
          new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            compress: {
              warning: true
            }
          })
        ]
      : [],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env), a platform-independent way to use environment variables:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack && gulp",
    // or if the former does not work
    "build": "npm run build:webpack && gulp",
    "build:webpack": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
},
```

Note that there are [other ways to do production builds](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/) or [evaluate environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) in the webpack configuration.

Comment: You are a genius! So I looked at the other option you posted and it seemed like you had to have 3 different webpack files. Is this way more optimized?

Comment: Splitting up the configuration into separate files is popular among some developers/projects. I'm not a fan of it since it makes navigating to the relevant part of the configuration more difficult. Alternatively you might want to [evaluate environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) in the webpack configuration.